# How to trigger onchange event without submitting the form?

Tags: rust, thirtyfour

I am using [thirtyfour](https://docs.rs/thirtyfour/latest/thirtyfour/)

```rust
let transfer_balance = self
     .driver
      .find(By::XPath("//*[contains(@name, 'transfer_balance')]"))
      .await?;
transfer_balance.send_keys(amount.to_string()).await?;
transfer_balance.send_keys(Key::Return.to_string()).await?;
```

`transfer_balance.send_keys(Key::Return.to_string()).await?;`

The Return key submits the form instead of just triggering onchange. How to solve the issue?

Yew html code

```rust
<div class="container">
    <form onsubmit={onsubmit} id="balance-transfer-from">
    <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="Destination Account" class="form-label">{"Destination Account Address:"}</label>
    <input name="destination_account" type="text" class="form-control" required={true} onchange={dest_account_onchanged}/>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="Transfer Balance" class="form-label">{"Transfer Balance:"}</label>
    <input name="transfer_balance" type="text" class="form-control" required={true} onchange={transfer_balance_onchanged}/>
    </div>
    if let Some(_value) = *spinner {
        <button type="submit" disabled={true} id="tranfer-balance-submit">{"Submit"}</button>
        <Icon icon_id={IconId::FontAwesomeSolidSpinner} />
    } else {
        <button type="submit" id="tranfer-balance-submit">{"Submit"}</button>
    }
</form>
```

Comment: What's the form in question? Where is the `onchange` event handler attached to?

Comment: Yes. `onchange` event handler.

Comment: Can't check it myself right now, but shouldn't `change` event fire on simply shifting the focus away from the changed field (i.e. focusing something else, for example, by sending `Tab` keypress)? It should not require pressing `Enter`.